# How to create 2 horizontal scroll bars with reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have the following solutions in jquery for 2 horizontal scrollbars for a data table.

```
$(function () {
    $('.wrapper1').on('scroll', function (e) {
        $('.wrapper2').scrollLeft($('.wrapper1').scrollLeft());
    }); 
    $('.wrapper2').on('scroll', function (e) {
        $('.wrapper1').scrollLeft($('.wrapper2').scrollLeft());
    });
});
$(window).on('load', function (e) {
    $('.div1').width($('table').width());
    $('.div2').width($('table').width());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/67xSL/71/

How would you go about writing this in Reactjs?

Comment: I assume you've done some basic react tutorials? Or have a test project? Generally you should aim to try then ask. It's better to come here asking how to fix an issue or for help with a problem than to straight up ask people to write features for you.

Comment: I recommend trying to implement yourself and see how far you get :) Then ask for help if you're stuck

Answer (score 0):

In `componentDidMount` you can do like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper2')[0].addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper1')[0].scrollLeft = 
  document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper2')[0].scrollLeft;
})

document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper1')[0].addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper2')[0].scrollLeft = 
  document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper1')[0].scrollLeft;
})
```

Hope it help you :)